# making test file for game called stendal in java

Tags: java, unit-testing

This is the file quitAction.java
And I need create a test file for it.

```
/* $Id$ */
/***************************************************************************
 *                   (C) Copyright 2003-2010 - Stendhal                    *
 ***************************************************************************
 ***************************************************************************
 *                                                                         *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
 *   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
 *                                                                         *
 ***************************************************************************/
package games.stendhal.client.actions;

import games.stendhal.client.gui.j2DClient;

/**
 * Quit the client.
 */
class QuitAction implements SlashAction {

    /**
     * Execute a chat command.
     *
     * @param params
     *            The formal parameters.
     * @param remainder
     *            Line content after parameters.
     *
     * @return <code>true</code> if was handled.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean execute(final String[] params, final String remainder) {
        j2DClient client = j2DClient.get();
        if (client != null) {
            client.requestQuit();
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the maximum number of formal parameters.
     *
     * @return The parameter count.
     */
    @Override
    public int getMaximumParameters() {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Get the minimum number of formal parameters.
     *
     * @return The parameter count.
     */
    @Override
    public int getMinimumParameters() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is my test.My understanding is it is ok as long as action.execute run, no override needed since /quit command do not need any argument.

```
public class QuitActionTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        StendhalClient.resetClient();
    }

    /**
     * Tests for execute.
     */
    @Test
    public void testExecute() {
        final QuitAction action = new QuitAction();
        assertThat(action.execute(null, null),is(true));
    }

    /**
     * Tests for getMaximumParameters.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetMaximumParameters() {
        final QuitAction action = new QuitAction();
        assertThat(action.getMaximumParameters(), is(0));
    }

    /**
     * Tests for getMinimumParameters.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetMinimumParameters() {
        final QuitAction action = new QuitAction();
        assertThat(action.getMinimumParameters(), is(0));
    }

}
```

But when I run junit test, it stops at testExecute() and I do not know why.
Of course testGetMinimumParameters() and testGetMaximumParameters() are ok.

Comment: What do you mean "it stops"? Do you mean the test exits? Or it hangs? Or...?

Comment: It only run 1/3 and it pause at TestExecute

Comment: What is it doing when it is "paused"? (It's very unlikely the answer is "nothing". Threads sleep, they get blocked on IO, they do expensive calculations...)

Comment: If the client is null in your test, the test will stop because of the System.exit(0).